# Is there any plugin available for Hudosn and HP ALM 11 integration

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I want to integrate Hudson and HP ALM 11 (Quality Center). So that once test cases are run those are also uploaded back into QC. Is there any plugin available or how should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools)—maybe it is possible to bring it to Hudson?

We use the OTA API from HP ALM to import test results: A Ruby script is triggered from the CI server at the end of the job. It creates test runs in HP ALM. Another possibility might be to use the REST API which was introduced in HP ALM 11.